# why does awaiter.IsCompleted always return false?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, client, httpclient

I'm new to .NET and writing a program for test.Right now I'm using TaskAwaiter and when I get awaiter from it's instance, it always returns false on awaiter.IsCompleted and I don't know why and how to fix it? Am I using it wrong?

```
TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage> awaiter;
str = "login.action";
awaiter = client.client.GetAsync(str).GetAwaiter();
if (awaiter.IsCompleted)
{
  break;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to have completed immediately? (It will have completed if GetAsync is actually synchronous, but that's all.) The whole point of asynchronous operations is that you start something, and can later wait for it to have completed. If it always completes immediately, it's not really asynchronous.

Comment: @JonSkeet but when do we find out it's completed?

Comment: By registering a completion handler. But you should rarely deal with an awaiter directly anyway - you'd normally just await the task instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I using it wrong?

You are assuming a HTTP request happens immediately. This is not the case. You have to await it.

There are edge cases where the called async method may not be async - i.e. returning a cached result - and those are the ONLY cases you willl get an IsCompleted = true right after calling in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If I put it in a while loop like 'while(!awaiter.IsCompleted)', will it fix that?

Comment: Or you jsut await it. Look at the methods in the awaiter, you know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have no a correct cycle definition.
It should be something like this:

```
TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage> awaiter;
str = "login.action";
awaiter = client.client.GetAsync(str).GetAwaiter();
while (true)
{
  if (awaiter.IsCompleted)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Or it will be better to write this way:
`while (!awaiter.IsComleted) {}`

Or the best pactice is use `async/await` keywords. For example:

```
public async Task YourMethodName()
{
  ...
  str = "login.action";
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.client.GetAsync(str);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse you can. But it is absolutely terrible thing to use such constructions. It means you will wait for 5sec anyway. But maybe you response will be received in a half of a second. So you will waste 4+ seconds.